# Advanced RPG-Style Movement in XNA

Tags: xna

I am making a top down, rpg-type game - similar to Pokemon, but I am stuck at character movement. Basically, what I want to achieve is a smooth tile based movement system for my player and other people on the map. Has anyone managed to do this effectively? If so, how?

Comment: how are you moving charachters right now ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a grid system, like Pokémon uses, you might be able to achieve this by setting a speed at which they can move between tiles.

For example, if you made it so that they can move one tile a second, you can then use `(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` in your `Update` function to determine how quickly the game is updating.  From this, you should be able to make it so that the character moves `((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * TileSize)` each update.

This would mean that if they have 4 updates a second (very slow, but for example), they would move 1/4 of the distance across the tile every update, and reach the end point by the end of the movement time period (1 second in this case).  In this situation, if you had 32 pixel tiles, they would move `0.25 * 32` every update, or 8 pixels.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very interesting... Thank you! I will give this a go as soon as possible!

Comment: I'm glad I could give you a starting point, best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

The 'technical' word for what you want is probably 'interpolation'.

I think the simplest thing you want to do is interpolate the unit position between its starting point (the middle of starting tile) and its ending point (the middle of ending tile) in the time period you want to give it a smooth movement.

Formula goes something like this:

```
float k = timeSinceStarted / durationOfMovement;
pos.X = startPos.X + (endPos.X - startPos.X) * k;
pos.Y = startPos.Y + (endPos.Y - startPos.Y) * k;
```

In a game, it's probably better to pre-compute the delta, and add increments instead of storing start position. Something like this (Note: I haven't double checked this computation).

```
delta = endPos - startPos;

position += delta * (timeSinceLastUpdate / durationOfMovement);
```